# How can I make a div fill the whole possible width after giving margins both to left and right?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a div fill the possible place after its margins taking effect.

For example if the screen width is 200 and the class is declared as below:

```css
.mini_video {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Can the `mini_video` have 160px width and be in the middle?

I am also using Bootstrap if it can help me in any way.

Comment: use padding instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be using padding for this use case. You could use an outside container and add padding to it for the video. Object-fit on the video allows it to scale progressively.

```
.mini_video-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: orange;
}
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jeffteachestheweb/pen/abJVNjg

Comment: Why? Why is padding better than margin? Why would margin not work? Why the `height: 100%`? Why `1000px`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `max-width: 100%;` instead of `width: 100%;`

```
.mini_video {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px; 
}
```

Take a look at that example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mini_video {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mini_video">Hello World</div>
```